# Is there a way to obtain the loss values for specific validation data for a Keras autoencoder?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to obtain the loss of each image compared to the autoencoder prediction. I am able to obtain the mean loss per epoch, but I would like to see how it holds for different types of images (slightly different from the trained set) to see how it performs.

Answer (score 0):

Found it here: https://keras.io/api/losses/ under "Standalone usage of loss".

Comment: Dead links may occur. It is helpful to copy/paste the relevant section of the document you are linking to.